# Can't import a database from SQLyog to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, importerror, sqlyog

I have created a database in SQLYog but I need to import it into phpMyAdmin because there isn't any port of SQLYog into linux, so I need this to continue with my project.
But when I tried to import my database into the phpMyAdmin the following error shows up:

```
CREATE TABLE `boletos`(
`Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Cantidad` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Salaid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Peliculaid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`horarioid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Precio` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`Total` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`Fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
`Hora` TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`Id`),
KEY `Peliculaid`(`Peliculaid`),
KEY `Salaid`(`Salaid`),
KEY `horarioid`(`horarioid`),
CONSTRAINT `boletos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY(`Peliculaid`) REFERENCES `peliculas`(`Id`),
CONSTRAINT `boletos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY(`Salaid`) REFERENCES `salas`(`Id`),
CONSTRAINT `boletos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY(`horarioid`) REFERENCES `horarios`(`Id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table `cine`.`boletos` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I know that there is a "syntax" error in the code, **but**, this code function perfectly with MySQL Workbench and SQLYog.

Comment: Have the 3 referenced tables been created before attempting to create boletos?

Comment: I don't have anything, the problem here is that I can't import a database to phpmyadmin